# Add commit to Manifest in Gradle based Spring Rest project

Tags: java, git, gradle

**I want to add the commit hash to the `MANIFEST` when building a `jar`.**

The context is as follows:

I have a `gradle` based project with `Spring-boot` dependencies. It is a `REST` api project. This is my hypothesis: All the plugins I've tried are override by the `buildJar` task provided by the `Spring` dependencies.

So my question is the following,

**how may I add the commit hash to the manifest by defining a very simple gradle task in the project?**

I already know how to print the last hash with the following task

```
task getHash {
    def p1 = 'git rev-parse HEAD'.execute()
    p1.waitFor()
    println p1.text
}
```

Here is the `build.gradle` detail:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.foo.bar'
version = '0.0.4-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Spring dependencies
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    //Clickhouse-jdbc
    compile group: 'ru.yandex.clickhouse', name: 'clickhouse-jdbc', version: '0.1.40'

    // Swagger
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'


    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot gradle plugin to generate a *fat-jar*, then you can configure the MANIFEST for this *fat-jar* using `bootJar` configuration extension, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring boot provides a `bootJar` extension that you can use to configure the MANIFEST:

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "GIT_REV": getHash()
        )
    }
}
```

you can define `getHash()` as a simple function within the build script:

```
ext.getHash = {
    def p1 = 'git rev-parse HEAD'.execute()
    p1.waitFor()
    return p1.text
}
```

For reference: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class

**Note**: this simple example should not be copy&paste as is: you should invoque the `getHash()` method during *build phase*, not during *configuration phase*.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks.